# Using Python with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, openshift

I've set up an Application on OpenShift like this:

[image]

I am using Flask with python on the server-side.

**Note:** I just need to connect Python to MySQL, Flask is irrelevant.

My `Hello World` program works fine:

**flaskapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In the **requirements.txt** the following dependency was added: `Flask==0.10.1`

I'm wondering is it necessary to add the `MySQL` dependency, like this: `MySQLdb==5.5`?

I've tried importing and using `MySQL` in **flaskapp.py** like this:

```
from flask import Flask
import mysql # I tried MySQLdb as well

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():

    output = ''

    db = mysql.connect(host="mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="adminIChJ87N",   
                     passwd="mypassword",  
                     db="python")  

    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable")

    for row in cur.fetchall():
        output+=row[0]

    db.close()  
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

How exactly do I use this `MySQL` database with Python? There seems to be no code on `Openshift`'s website

Comment: I don't know the answer but maybe these link can help :D

https://developers.openshift.com/en/python-flask.html#next
http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/

Comment: What error message do you see when run the above code? Does the database not connect? Or does the `fetchall()` doesn't return what is intended to return? A little more context please :)

Comment: Apologies. The error is that the dependency `MySQLdb==5.5` doesn't exist. My main question is whether I should be using `pymysql` or `MySqldb`or another database with `OpenShift`. I'm sure if I installed the correct library locally it would work, and I'd see the errors (if there were any). But my problem is running it live, which database library do I use with OpenShift, and how do I import it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the package for MySQLdb is [`mysqlclient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) (if you want it to work with Python3, otherwise it is a fork of `MySQL-python`). So this is what you need to put in the dependencies. Run `pip install mysqlclient` to try it.

Comment: Apologies if I should know this. I'm using Python 2.7. Do I still `import mysqlclient`? And how do I add to the dependencies. `MySQL-python==5.5`? I also tried running `pip install mysqlclient` on my machine for `localhost` and got error `error code 1` stating `mysql_config not found`. Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I could maybe use `virtualenv` to install the package on the server but apparently `requirements.txt` is much better. The problem is, I have no idea how openshift recognizes these dependecies, by what name and version number?

Comment: I fixed the local error, imported `_mysql` or `MySQLdb`, still not sure what to do with the dependencies on the server though

Comment: You still need to import it, and indeed it is `import _mysql` for some reason. Could it be that you got this error because you did not install MySQL/MariaDB in the first place ? The requirements are usually specified in setup.py, although that one itself could read them from a requirements.txt.

Comment: I installed `MySQL` and fixed the previous error. However, on running `wsgi.py` locally I get a new error `image not found` which seems to have many solutions on SO, none which are helping me. Aside from my local setup, I'm still having problems with the server setup. I can't locate the requirements specifications so I still get an error on the server. Is it just a case of finding out what to put into the `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: I think this is no more a Python/MySQL question, so you should open a new question, tagged 'Flask'.

Comment: I actually fixed my Local Error, so I can test here fine. I suppose it's more of an OpenShift question maybe? How to set up the requirements for mysql?